# Cant display multiple quill-view-html

Tags: angular, ngx-quill

I am attempting to display multiple ngx-quill inputs, but when I use `quill-view-html` it hides the the html bellow it. Is this just a thing or is there a configuration that can prevent this?

For context, Basically I have an array of strings from a quill editor and I pass each of them into the quill view component, but it erases everything bellow it.

Thanks!